# Visual studio 2010 if line doesnt work

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

Why isn't this working?

```
If (Status = "1") Then
        Me.DPD.Visible = False
End If
```

> Error: Error   9   Overload resolution failed because no accessible '=' can be called with these arguments:
>       'Public Shared Operator =(a As String, b As String) As Boolean': Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: `Status` appears to be `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`

Comment: Are you **sure** this is C#?

Comment: @mattytommo lol it's not. Looks like he chose tags randomly.

Comment: If Status is a string, may want to try Status.equals("1")

Comment: The compiler is trying to tell you that `Status` is a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, not a `String`, and that no implicit conversion exists between one and the other.

Comment: This is the type of question that makes me question someone should program. If you choose tags by random and are not able to read an error text - maybe, just maybe, getting an xbox is more productive.

Comment: @TomTom usually I would consider such comment rude but after reading again and especially the comment on my answer, well... it sounds more like the harsh truth.

Answer (score 4):

The variable `Status` is of type DataGridViewTextBoxColumn. You probably want to get its name, so proper code would be:

```
If (Status.Name = "1") Then
    Me.DPD.Visible = False
End If
```

Comment: Status.equals("1") was the the thing i needed, user Mike answered that in the comments. Thanks for your replies anyway.

Comment: @user3279834 but Status is **not** a string, and your condition will always be False. You'll figure this out eventually. You can also have `If (1 = 2) Then` with exact same effect.